# CakePhp will not start after being moved

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, opensuse

I had to setup a new server. During this process I copied my Cake app to the new system. By doing this the path changend from `/data/nas/www/htdocs/adfund` to `/srv/www/htdocs/adfund`. Now the app does not start anymore.

I tested console command `Console/cake EmailQueue.sender` and it came up with this error:

```
PHP Warning:  include(/data/nas/www/htdocs/adfund/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/www/htdocs/adfund/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 548
```

To me this looks like some the app has stored the old path and tries to include from there.

Any idea where this could take place?

Old System: Eisfair
New System: OpenSUSE

Comment: Fund a part of this problem: I had to empty '/tmp/cache/persistent'

Comment: "_a part_" means it's fixed? Further hardcoded paths may be found in `app/webroot/index.php`.

Comment: delete all your cache files, not just the persistent ones

Answer (score 0):

You should completly wipe your cache directories. If there are still problems check your .htaccess file if RewriteBase is set wrong.